# custom post type and taxonomies in a php class

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I used this class in the tutorial to create two custom post types

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-post-type-helper-class--wp-25104

According to `add_taxonomy()` function if the taxonomy already exists then `$E2` will be added to that taxonomy. this is achieved by using `taxonomy_exists()`

```
if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy_name ) )
{
    /* Create taxonomy and attach it to the object type (post type) */
    // register_taxonomy()
}
else
{
    /* The taxonomy already exists. We are going to attach the existing taxonomy to the object type (post type) */
   // register_taxonomy_for_object_type()
}
```

here logic is correct but when ever i register a taxonomy for two post_type's only the second post_type will get this taxonomy, first post_type will not be registered with taxonomy

```
$E1 = new Custom_Post_Type('E1');   
$E2 = new Custom_Post_Type('E2');

$E1->add_taxonomy( 'tax1' );   
$E2->add_taxonomy( 'tax1' );
```

upon debugging i found out that `taxonomy_exists()` returns false even when taxonomy is registered.

I tried making $wp_taxonomies global since it holds all taxonomies, but no use.

so problem is with detecting whether a taxonomy is already registered or not.

Comment: "that taxonomy_exists() returns false even when taxonomy is registered" how are you confident that it _is_ registered at that poing in execution, when function that exists solely to check that tells you that it's not?

Comment: Because i tired to debug it with xDebug and it returned false every time. but taxonomies are registered for last called post_type

Comment: Could you provide some code for how are you checking that?